# Dicom files: how to extract brain/organ from MRI scan?

Tags: 3d, dicom

This is technically not a graphic design question, but it is technically not *not* a graphic design question either, so here I go.

I have a set of MRI scans of my head. They are 5mm slices in x,y,z (or if you prefer med-speak: saggital, coronal, axial). (I also have some sets in 1.5mm slices, but they are incomplete. I.e. only a section, not the entire brain.). 
[image]
My ultimate goal is to extract the brain only, and have it 3D printed. I am using Osirix (though I have Slicer, but have not tried it yet).

I *could* hand-draw the outline of the brain in each individual slice, but apart from taking weeks to do properly, I am not sure the resulting slices will add up to anything near good enough (If I *knew* it would turn out good, I would consider it). But there have to be a better way.

I have tried to make a 3D model of the entire head using 3D surface rendering, and the result even of that is rather disappointing:
[image]

I have also tried using the "growing" tool, where, as far as I understand, I should be able to select a colour/density and then removing everything else.

As I see it, there are two ideas, but they both boil down to the same:
How to select one organ, when the other organs and tissue close to it are much of the same density? (the inverse approach would be; instead of *extracting* something spesific, then *delete* what is not needed).

I realise that if I am ever successful in extracting the brain, there will be the voxel lego-effect (albeit in x, y, z), and I would also need to set some smoothing parameters.

So. In short:

- What settings (for contrast/density/tissue type/bone) do I set, to
  make the extraction possible?
- Do I use the "grow" tool, and if so, how do I get it to select all
  voxels in all three series?
- If not the grow tool... then what?
- If I get it extracted, where and how do I determine smooting options?

Comment: This really boils down to: how do I create a mask from this imagery? You are only interested in the outer edge of the brain. In the sample images--in the narrow band which can be loosely  described as an ellipse--I see a high contrast bewteen the part you want and the part you don't. If you mask quickly mask the inner part you don't want and the outer part you don't want, the problem of edge detection becomes a lot easier, especially using a threshold filter.

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484577/volume-render-dicomdir-ct-scan) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @horatio, yes you are technically right, but the images you see does not show the slices where the contrast is very, very low. Technically, dicom files are not really concerned with colour as such, but density. There must be a density-difference in those low-contrast areas that might well have a default "extract organ" tool. I am just a noob in Osirix.

Comment: @AlexBlackwood yes, I have been past that post a long while ago, and I will look into it again, but what I found then, was not helpful. It might just boil down to my Royal Noobness regarding Osirix and medical jargon.

Comment: I do not know what medium the data is stored as: is it fixed pixel data; is it a raw data map which has a color gradient applied to it; can the visualization be weighted/adjusted/multiplied rescaled? If you can get the boundary that you are interested in to be well-demarcated via color-ramping/threshold/etc, you can use any graphic tool to silhouette the shape.

Comment: In other words: if you can get anything that is not black to blast out to white (or anything that is lighter than that very darkest blue), you are probably 90% there.

Comment: @horatio, well, not really. That is the basic idea, but these are medical dicom files with slices x,y,z, and what I need to do is in _theory_ what you say, but automated through Osirix (or Slicer) as these are volume files with voxels.

Comment: You might enjoy Markus van Almsick's [video presentation on 3D images in Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=105/?fp=left&video=1554). In the second half he examines an MRI brain scan.

Comment: can I use the above image for my research as reference color image ,please guide me the procedure

Comment: @shwetha you are welcome to use my images above. What you mean by guiding, I don’t know. If you want to experiment with Dicom files yourself I suggest searching for tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

In order to render just the brain you need to perform  a [volume render](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_rendering) (it's different from a surface render), better if after a semi-automatic [segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation).

The segmentation provides the set of the data with the needed density. Without a segmentation you can use built-in volumetric filters and obtain a rough reconstruction. This is possible in [ImageJ](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/) too.

I've more experience with [Slicer](http://www.slicer.org/) (see a tutorial [here](http://www.slicer.org/slicerWiki/images/2/24/AutomaticSegmentation_SoniaPujol.pdf)), but I'm sure that [OsiriX](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/) can perform a correct segmentation as well.

There are a lot of tutorials on brain segmentation with OsiriX, for example [here](http://www.bmc.med.utoronto.ca/bmcwiki/doku.php/technologies%3aosirix%3atutorial%3abrainct) (CT brain data) or [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFdrU3JWB_o) (head). There is a [segmentation plugin](http://campar.in.tum.de/Students/SepOsiriXSegmentation) for OsiriX (not tried).

Be aware that segmentation is a slow technique and needs a certain time to be properly used.

Comment: Hurray - I will dig into it in a little later: will report back.

Comment: Give also a look to [this tool](http://qcganime.web.fc2.com/OOSAWA/oosawaE.html), I have not yet tested it, but it seems to be able to open the slices and export them in DF3 format.

Answer (score 1):

As a layman (a physician by profession but not a 3D modeling guy), I like the 3D-Doctor.  Maybe it'll give some clue to your question:
http://www.ablesw.com/3d-doctor/tutor.html